# Best practice mongodump backing up 250GB database

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm tring another aproach. Full dump and the daily dump of new data using:

`oid=$(mongo --quiet --eval 'ObjectId.fromDate(ISODate("2017-03-29 00:10:20"))')`

`mongodump -q "{_id:{$gt:$oid}}" -d dbname --collection name_data`

But I'm getting:

`Failed: error parsing query as json: invalid character ':' looking for beginning of object key string`

Comment: Have you looked into the various options described at the [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first $ needs to be escaped:

mongodump -q "{_id:{\$gt:$oid}}" -d dbname --collection name_data